# Spring JPA Error creating SessionFactory -org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring, jpa, maven-3

I Have created a Spring WS, now i want to add some funcionality by enabling JPA - i am kind of newbie so I opened one of tutorials and do as it was said to do.
And i found problem i can't solve fast enough.. When i want to create SessionFactory and DataSource for my database like that:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>    
  </bean>
```

with my Maven dependancies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

i got following HTTP 500 error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Im quite sure that this is problem with my dependancies. But i have tried so many combinations and nothing works for me... Do anyone have a clue what i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Hibernate to your dependencies.

Note that you say that you want JPA, but your configuration actually uses raw Hibenate API instead.

If you really want raw Hibernate API, add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want Hibernate with JPA API, add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

You also may want to use Hibernate 4.x instead (for raw Hibernate API, you need to use `...hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` in this case).

Comment: adding dependancy you have provided couse pom.xml error:ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javassist/javassist/3.12.0.GA/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar

Comment: @GrzegorzS: I think you have some problem with your Maven repository configuration. This dependency is indeed present in Maven Central.